# Tensorflow: How can I assign numpy pre-trained weights to subsections of graph?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

This is a simple thing which I just couldn't figure out how to do.

I converted a pre-trained VGG caffe model to tensorflow using the github code from https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow and saved it to vgg16.npy...

I then load the network to my sess default session as "net" using:

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 224, 224, 3])
net = VGGNet_xavier({'data': images, 'label' : 1}) 
with tf.Session() as sess:
  net.load("vgg16.npy", sess)
```

After net.load, I get a graph with a list of tensors. I can access individual tensors per layer using net.layers['conv1_1']... to get weights and biases for the first VGG convolutional layer, etc.

Now suppose that I make another graph that has as its first layer "h_conv1_b":

```
  W_conv1_b = weight_variable([3,3,3,64])
  b_conv1_b = bias_variable([64])
  h_conv1_b = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(im_batch, W_conv1_b) + b_conv1_b)
```

My question is -- how do you get to assign the pre-trained weights from net.layers['conv1_1'] to h_conv1_b ?? (both are now tensors)

Comment: You seem to be saying that your `net.load()` already loads things into TF tensors. So what exactly prevents you from simply doing `W_conv1_b = net.layers['conv1_1'].weights` or something like that?

Answer (score 19):

I suggest you have a detailed look at [network.py](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow/blob/master/kaffe/tensorflow/network.py) from the https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow, especially the function `load()`. It would help you understand what happened when you called `net.load(weight_path, session)`.

FYI, variables in Tensorflow can be assigned to a numpy array by using `var.assign(np_array)` which is executed in the session. Here is the solution to your question:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
  W_conv1_b = weight_variable([3,3,3,64])
  sess.run(W_conv1_b.assign(net.layers['conv1_1'].weights))
  b_conv1_b = bias_variable([64])
  sess.run(b_conv1_b.assign(net.layers['conv1_1'].biases))
  h_conv1_b = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(im_batch, W_conv1_b) + b_conv1_b)
```

I would like to kindly remind you the following points:

1. `var.assign(data)` where 'data' is a numpy array and 'var' is a TensorFlow variable should be executed in the same session where you want to continue to execute your network either inference or training.
2. The 'var' should be created as the same shape as the 'data' by default. Therefore, if you can obtain the 'data' before creating the 'var', I suggest you create the 'var' by the method `var=tf.Variable(shape=data.shape)`. Otherwise, you need to create the 'var' by the method `var=tf.Variable(validate_shape=False)`, which means the variable shape is feasible. Detailed explainations can be found in the Tensorflow's API doc.

I extend the same repo caffe-tensorflow to support theano in caffe so that I can load the transformed model from caffe in Theano. Therefore, I am a reasonable expert w.r.t this repo's code. Please feel free to get in contact with me as you have any further question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get variable values using [eval](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#eval) method of `tf.Variable`-s from the first network and load that values into variables of the second network using [load](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load) method (also method of the `tf.Variable`).