# Tensorflow 2.x: How to assign convolution weights manually using numpy

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, onnx

In tensorflow 1.x this can be done using a [graph and a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555256/tensorflow-how-can-i-assign-numpy-pre-trained-weights-to-subsections-of-graph), which is quite tedious.

Is there an easier way to manually assign pretrained weights to a specific convolution in tensorflow 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Keras inside Tensorflow 2.x, every layer has a method called `set_weights` that you can use to substitute weights or assign new ones from Numpy arrays.

Say, for example, that you are doing distillation knowledge. Then you could assign weights of the teacher to the student by:

`conv.set_weights(teacher.convx.get_weights())`

where `conv` is a particular layer of the student and `convx` the homologue of the teacher.

You can check the documentation for more details:

[Documentation - set_weights()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights)